# running a spring hibernate web application on jetty and tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat, jetty

I have created a spring-hibernate web application and it is running perfectly on jetty server.

However when I run it on tomcat it ran successfully with no errors, but I am not able to use the application on web browser, nothing shows up on web browser(not even error).

Below are the details:

This is where the application successfully starts using jetty server.

> http://localhost:8080/contacts

This is where I have defined the controller for the same.

```
@Controller
public class ContactController {

    @Autowired
    private ContactRepository contactRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/contacts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getContactList(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("contacts", contactRepository.findAll());
        return "contact/list";
    }

}
```

web.xml file.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/view/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>openEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>entityManagerFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>openEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Below is spring-servlet.xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.marakana.contacts.controllers" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe for tomcat url should be http://localhost:8080/yourWarName/contacts

Comment: So how does it works.. I mean why didn't it ask for war-name in case of jetty?

Comment: Well by default jetty should ask war name too, becouse you can deploy several applications. https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.0.v20150612/automatic-webapp-deployment.html

Comment: I didn't do anything .. just mentioned jetty in pom.xml and when i ran my application using maven it was working ..

Comment: You using jetty maven plugin?

Comment: Yes, the one which is built in Eclipse

Comment: jetty documentation tell us that by default, context path set to /. http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#configuring-your-webapp , and tomcat documentation tell us that the default context path is /${project.artifactId}. http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html.